# MeshLab UV Map issue

Tags: meshlab

On MeshLab_64bit_fp v2016.12 ,I have a issue with the UV Map being "destroyed" and was wondering if there is a way around it.

[Original UV Map](https://gyazo.com/00df55b5ede79362d39f09b68c365a0c) <-- That's what its supposed to look like.

Though when using the following filter --> [Filter Settings](https://gyazo.com/00f7f37a4bf4adc4bc3bc83dea00eba9)

What then happens to the UV Map, looks like this: [UV Map End Result](https://gyazo.com/14911cbec44f2c33ba5430e4255711d1)

So is there anyway to keep the UV Map filling out the same space or do I just have to remap it from scratch?

Plus "if" there is currently no fix to that at the moment, are there plans to fix this issue later on?

Comment: Came up with sort of an answer to my question awhile back, figured I'd say it here. From the looks of it, there was an issue with the mesh itself. When testing with other meshes the problem doesn't occur. Though I couldn't tell you why the issue occurred for that specific mesh that had the problem that I've shown.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are using the Quadric Edge Collapse *with Texture* Filter.  I haven't had problems with it retaining the UV map.